# Xml diff compare in dotnet core 2.0

Tags: xml, compare, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am writing an MVC webapp in AspNetCore 2.0 and need to identify and locate changes in xml documents i produce so I can mark the changed elements and determine if a minor or major version increment is needed.

When searching for answers on how to do this I did not find many concrete answers.

I found a port of the old XmlDiffPatch tool but it requires framework and apparently don't work on core. The functionality of this class is a little sparse but very nice and fast and once I figured out how the diffgram was structured i could easily use it to identify the changed sections in my document.

However I was thinking (hoping) that the reason for not finding many posts about the subject maybe is that this is such a trivial task that no one cared to write about it.

What is currently the best api for performing this task?

(What are the odds that corefx team will introduce XmlDiffPatch to core 2.0?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After hours of further research I came to the conclusion that the XmlDiffPatch had the functionality I liked most and I found that if I installed [.Net framework 1.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=26), I could install the toolkit from [MS Download](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/f/1/1f146f9b-2a71-4904-8b91-e2f62d7b64b3/XmlDiffPatch.exe) and in this was included the original source code.

I put the .cs files into a new NetStandard2.0 classlib project and the code compiled without issues.

<s>I pushed a package named [XmlDiffPatch.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XmlDiffPatch.Core/) to NuGet and also did the same for XmlDiffView (called [XmlDiffView.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XmlDiffView.Core/)) so others can use it.</s> (The packages have been delisted on NuGet)

Comment: Hi, could you please share source code for those two nuget packages? It would be very beneficial as over time this could get lost again

Comment: Does your package include the HTML generation too? I found that very useful in the past - but it's a little outdated with hardcoded styles IIRC.

Comment: nvm! I see you mentioned it but just didn't link it. I've edited your answer to add links

Comment: @henrik I noticed that your version of `XmlDiffView` has `GetHtml` but also a whole bunch of other methods. The `GetHtml` gives completely different results than the original XmlDiffView did. Instead of colorizing the differences it puts lots of `1` in a third column and I couldn't really figure out what was going on. I had to go back to the source myself (in `Samples\XmlDiffView`) to get it working as I wanted. So I'm not sure what you did - but anyone else trying to get colorized differences may have to do this too. And I can confirm on Win 10 that installing Framework 1.1 works fine.